# Recurrence $(n+2)\text{Cat}_{n+1}=(4n+2)\text{Cat}_n$ for non-crossing matchings

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

The number of non-crossing matchings of sides of $2n$-gon (i.e. the number of ways to connect sides pairwise by non-intersecting paths) is $n$’th Catalan number, $\text{Cat}_n$.

> How to prove combinatorially that $(n+2)\text{Cat}_{n+1}=(4n+2)\text{Cat}_n$ for *this* interpretation of Catalan numbers?

---

For example, proof of this recurrence for triangulations of $(n+2)$-gon is [described in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Fourth_proof): after choosing a side of $(n+3)$-gon and contracting corresp. triangle we get an $(n+2)$-gon with one (marked and) oriented edge — I want something like this.

In principle, triangulations and non-crossing matchings are connected by a chain of bijections (e.g. matchings $\leftrightarrow$ balanced parentheses $\leftrightarrow$ binary trees $\leftrightarrow$ triangulations) and one can try to transfer the description from the previous paragraph via this chain. But this way quickly becomes too convoluted (for me, at least).

Answer (score 1):

(It will be slightly more convenient to use the language of non-crossing matchings of points on a line aka balanced parentheses.)

Let's call `()` (i.e. a pair of adjacent elements that are paired in the matching) a *leaf*. Each non-crossing matching has at least one leaf. To get the recurrence relation Let's count the number of non-crossing matchings of $2(n+1)$ elements with a marked leaf.

**Example** ($n=2$, leaves are red). $((\color{red}{()}))$, $\color{red}{()}\color{red}{()}\color{red}{()}$, $(\color{red}{()}\color{red}{()})$, $(\color{red}{()})\color{red}{()}$, $\color{red}{()}(\color{red}{()})$,

On one hand, there are $(2n+1)Cat_n$ such 'decorated' matchings (just throw away the marked leaf). On other hand, to get a decorated matching we just need to choose a leaf in one of $Cat_{n+1}$ matchings.

**Lemma.** *On average* an nc-matching of $2(n+1)$ elements has $(n+2)/2$ leaves.

(So once Lemma is proven we have $(2n+1)Cat_n=\frac{(n+2)}2Cat_{n+1}$, qed.)

To prove Lemma define an involution on nc-matchings by the rule $\overline{(\alpha)\beta}=(\overline\beta)\overline\alpha$. So, for example, $\overline{((()))}=()()()$, $\overline{()(())}=(()())$ (and vice versa), $\overline{(())()}=(())()$. Now observe that if $\sigma$ has $k$ leaves, $\overline\sigma$ has $n+2-k$ leaves, so we're done.

Comment: Understanding is its own reward.